# plt.bar (matplotlib in python) does not make bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a bar plot. I have count data that I have distributed into bins of size 1000 (say). On the x-axis, I have the bin coordinate, i.e., -3000, -2000, ..., 0, 1000, 2000, 3000 (in that form).

Now when I say plt.bar(x-coord, y-coord), I only get vertical lines.

How do I make sure I get bars? I did try playing around the width coordinate, but had no luck.

Thank you in advance for answering my question.

Comment: put your code so we can debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your barwidth is too small. Because your x values are so large, the bar appears only as a line.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27, 12, 38)
index = np.array((-3000, -2000, -1000, 0, 1000, 2000, 3000))
barwidth = 400
plt.bar(index, values, barwidth)
plt.xticks(index + barwidth/2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Arjun StackExchange gives the users the control over what's considered good, bad and right. This is done by voting mainly. Please have a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).